# Chart in Dynamics 365 Portal page is not filtering based on current logged in user

Tags: adxstudio-portals, dynamics-crm-portals

I am running Dynamics 365 Customer Self-Service Portal (v8.3.3.153) for CRM Online, and I'm having trouble getting a chart to display the correct data based on the currently logged-in user.  I set up a pie chart for cases and added that to the Support Home page which also has an entity list control to display cases based on different view selections.  So for example, if I am viewing open cases in the entity list, that is filtered by my currently logged in user so I have 5 cases, but the chart shows all open cases for all contacts (300+) when using the same view for the chart as for the entity list.  In my support home page I added Liquid code like this:

```
{% chart id:"F1F23F44-4C37-E811-811F-E0071B6AA291" viewid:"9F9AA5DC-A537-E511-947E-00155D038C01" %}
```

I tried the suggested view filter configuration based on the article [here](https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/configuration-guide/entity-list/enhanced-crm-view-filtering/), but that just resulted in my seeing no data in the chart, it seems that the portal page didn't automatically switch out the contact guid.

Is there any way to configure a chart to reflect the same filtering based on contact and/or parent account as can be done with the entity lists?

Answer (score 0):

I am also integrating charts on the Portal and noticed this behavior, but as I want to display this only to the Admin was not an issue.
It also happened to me to have filters not applied same way on the CRM and Portal. for example using a Lookup field value, seems more like a bug to me.
Give it a try to use the View on a Entitylist and see what kind of results you get there, otherwise I'll suggest you to raise a Ticket to Microsoft.